# Refresh getAuthToken

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i need to refresh the getAuthToken after it expires. I put the getAuthToken call inside the background.js and save the variable in storage so that the content script can receive it. So far so good. When the token expires rightly I receive the 401 code from the google drive API, then I send a message from the content script to the background.js so as to use the removeCachedAuthToken and then I redo the getAuthToken call and I go back to the token in the storage. All this works the user reloads the page keeping the extension open to pass the message from the content script to the background.js and reloading the content script again received the token to make the google drive api calls.

Is it possible to at least refresh the page and not just two?

Manifest.js

```
{
    "name": "Project",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "description": "Project",

    "icons": {
        "128": "img/path_128.png",
        "64": "img/path_64.png",
        "32": "img/path_32.png"
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Project"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Project",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "oauth2": {
        "client_id": "******.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "scopes":["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata"]
    },

    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "identity"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [
       {
         "css": ["css/google-docs.css"],
         "js": ["js/jquery-3.5.0.min.js", "js/google-docs.js"]

       }
     ],

    "content_security_policy": "script-src https://code.jquery.com https://apis.google.com 'self'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Background.js

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function(token) {
                /*chrome.storage.local.set({token: token}, function() {

                });*/
                console.log(token);
                chrome.storage.local.set({'token': token}, function() {
                  // Notify that we saved.
                  console.log('Settings saved');
                });
            });
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(request.greeting);
        if (request.greeting == "401"){
            chrome.storage.local.get('token', function(data) {
                var token = data.token;
                chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken({token: token}, function (){
                  alert('removed');
                    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: false}, function(token) {
                        console.log(token);
                        chrome.storage.local.set({'token': token}, function() {
                          // Notify that we saved.
                          console.log('Settings saved');
                          sendResponse({farewell: "success"});
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        }

});
```

Content.js (google-docs.js)

```
chrome.storage.local.get('token', function(data) {
        var token = data.token;
        console.log(token);
        AjaxCall(token);

});

// error code ajax function
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Error: ' + errorThrown + ' / ' + textStatus) + console.log(jqXHR);
                a = true;
                if(jqXHR.responseJSON.error.code){
                    token = refreshAuthTokenCall();
                }

            }

function refreshAuthTokenCall(){

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "401"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.farewell);
        if(response.farewell == "success"){
            chrome.storage.local.get('token', function(data) {
                var token = data.token;
                console.log(token);
                AjaxCall(token);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?  I can't understand 'Is it possible to at least refresh the page and not just two?', can you explain more?  Do you not want to refresh the page at all?  What do you mean by keeping the extension open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `chrome.identity` does not return a refresh token so the user will need to go through the user consent flow once the access token expires.